# How to get wiki pageid?

Tags: php, json, api, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am currently using PHP to make a chatbot that can do research on wiki,and send the introduction automaitcally, here is the wiki api json(https://zh.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=search_title)

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"redirects":[{"from":"search_title","to":"search_title"}],"pages":{"541":{"pageid":541,"ns":0,"title":"search_title","extract":"ablablablablablablablablablablabla。"}}}}
```

I want to get the extract part by

`$data=$jsondata['query']['pages']["541"]['extract'];`

but it seems like I need to have to know pageid is '541' first, is there method that I can know padeid in first??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for a way to iterate over array values without knowing the keys. I'm not a PHP developer but I think a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) will do:

```
foreach ($jsondata['query']['pages'] as $pageid => $pagedata) {
    extract = $pagedata['extract']
    ...
}
```

There is also a [`formatversion=2`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:JSON_version_2) parameter for the query that, among other things, will make

> action=query's "pages" be an array, instead of an object with page ids
>   as keys that can be difficult to iterate.